# Magento how update product price in cart

Tags: magento, cart

I want to update the product price depend on different sizes selected and quantity entered for the size (I am using the custom options for different sizes).

for example: 
I have one product with two different size options 
size 1: S 
size 2: M

where size 2 have cost with $2 extra. so if the product price is $14 and user select this size then this will charge user extra $2 for each M size quantity entered.

Another example:
Small size quantity: 5
Medium size quantity: 1

Then the product price will be 
5 * 14 = $70
1 * 16 = $16
Total price: $86

But according to magento this effect overall price:

```
6 * 16 = $96
```

so the product cost is $96 instead of $86.

Comment: Hell guys I have found the Solution of my Issue. You can view the answer at http://precticalsolution.blogspot.in/2013/03/magento-calculate-product-price-form.html. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which types do the products have? Configurable products should exist of a set Simple products which are or are not visible individually.

Since the configurable products is just a shell to keep it all together you can still alter the prices of the individual products.

For more info on configurable products, attributes and simple products check: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have tried configurable products but I can not use configurable products.
I am using simple products with custom options for size.
I have multiple sizes like small, medium, large, extra large
These all sizes have quantity also. so if any one choose small with quantity 2 and medium with quantity 1 then the products price would be as this.
(<small size prize> * <small size quantity entered>) + (<medium size prize> * <medium size quantity entered>)

This is my big issue.
Looking for more solutions.

Comment: Why can't you use configurable products? Magento is build to work with configurable products which can have one or more attributes which each can have different quantities when checking out. You should take a look at the link i provided earlier, the t-shirt case is explained there. I don't want to be harsh but this is really the way you should go in a Magento environment.